# If my Service Returns an IEnumerable of Entities, can I Lazy Load Related Entities?

Tags: .net, linq

I have this entity:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public ProductManufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

I want my Services to return a list of Products to display in a View. I also need to display information about the related manufacturer (Product.Manufacturer) using lazy loading.

Should my Services return an IQueryable or an IEnumerable? Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you intended these to be properties and not fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) are both interfaces. Neither of them "support" lazy loading.

Comment: Thank you @John Saunders, I just added more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think the items are not serialized before you use them, if that's what you mean. I have had issues with this, returning LINQ expressions from WCF services, and gotten exceptions when the WCF serializer tries to serialize the result. The solution is to call ToArray() on the IQueryable result before serializing it.

Don't know if that completely answers your question?